# Python | Pair Iteration List | Find position of "can" and "help" if they are within 3 words of each other in string

Tags: python, pandas

I already have a function that will identify all instances per row of a dataframe where a specified word is near another specified word ("can" near "help", within 3 words of each other):

```
def identify_instances(string, word_1 = 'can', word_2 = 'help', allowed_distance = 3):
    string_list = string.split(' ')
    indices_word_1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == word_1]
    indices_word_2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == word_2]
    result = 0
    for i in indices_word_1:
        for j in indices_word_2:
            _distance = abs(i - j)
            if _distance <= allowed_distance:
                result += 1
    return result

pandasDF['can_NEAR_help'] = pandasDF['String'].apply(lambda x: identify_instances(x))
```

However, I also need to show the word-positions for all the paired instances identified, expressed in the form of a Pairs List.

For example, in the following dummy data, the input and desired output would be like this:

```
data = [['ABC123', 'can you help me with this'], ['ABC456', 'I can not help with this, but 
they can help'], ['ABC789', 'No one can help can they']]
pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Record ID', 'String'])
print(pandasDF)

Record ID | can-NEAR-help Positions
----------|-----------------------
ABC123    | [(0, 2)]
ABC456    | [(1, 3), (8, 9)]
ABC456    | [(2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Can I just reference each "i" and "j" in the return-line of the function somehow?

```
for i in indices_word_1:
for j in indices_word_2:
    _distance = abs(i - j)
    if _distance <= allowed_distance:
        return i and return j ?
```

Comment: your second `for loop` is not properly indented

Comment: I just noticed and fixed it. Thanks

Comment: *" Can I just reference each "i" and "j" "* You reference them 2 lines above, I'm not sure why you'd think it would change on the last line

Comment: @DeepSpace because I meant reference them as like, a return line at the end, not when defining the function near the start. For each (i)instance in the string meeting criteria xyz, then return the (i)instance, obviously in combination with something else in the return in order to make it show the positions.

Comment: @DeepSpace To illustrate my point, I kinda/sorta got it to partially work just now by simply adding "return i" or "return j" for that last line of the function. It shows the position for I and J, just not paired together and only the first instance encountered.

Comment: Duplicate to [Count number of times a phrase is near another phrase, within n# of words of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175134/count-number-of-times-a-phrase-is-near-another-phrase-within-n-of-words-of-eac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pandas is not well suited to this problem, because pandas supports tabular data which should be only one value per cell. For example, if you switch to numpy, your problem becomes a bit easier.

```
def identify_instances(string, word_1 = 'can', word_2 = 'help', allowed_distance = 3):
    string_list = np.array(string.split(' '))
    first_word = string_list == word_1 #find matches for first word
    second_word = string_list == word_2 #find matches for second word
    matches = first_word[None] & second_word[:,None] #find matches for both words
    inds = np.stack(np.where(matches)).T #find indices of the above matches
    inds.sort() # in place
    inds = inds[(inds[:,1] - inds[:,0]) <= allowed_distance] #limit it to the close matches
    return [tuple(i) for i in inds] #get it in your pair list format

print(identify_instances('can you help me with this',word_1='can',word_2='help'))
> [(0, 2)]
print(identify_instances('I can not help with this, but they can help',word_1='can',word_2='help'))
> [(1, 3), (8, 9)]
```

If it HAS to be in a pandas dataframe just wrap the above in a string or something.